# silverlight - changing a value on property changed

Tags: silverlight, binding, textbox, inotifypropertychanged

I have a textbox bound to a decimal property called Amount, and a business rule that says the Amount value cannot be greater than 100. 
This is set up with proper MVVM and INotifyPropertyChanged events.

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Amount, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=N2}" />
```

When the Amount value changes, in the property set, I am checking if Amount > 100. If it is then I set the value to 100.

```
    private decimal _Amount;
    public decimal Amount
    {
        get { return _Amount; }
        set {
            if (value > 100)
                _Amount = 100
            else
                _Amount = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Amount");
        }
    }
```

Problem is **this new value never shows up in the textbox**, no matter how many times I throw the INotifyPropertyChangedEvent.

I tried throwing the INotifyPropertyChanged event on the TexBbox's LostFocus event, but that made the value reset to the original(unedited) value. That's because this event happens before the value reaches the property setter.

**Can anyone suggest a way for me to get the modified value to show up correctly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. Instead of resetting the value inside of the setter, I handled the object's PropertyChangedEvent and reset the value there.

Frustratingly, this solution was not working during debug, but works fine once its published.

Thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 0):

Add the UpdateSourceTrigger attribute to the textbox.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Amount, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

Comment: When I do this the user encounters some weird cursor re-positioning. For example, if they type in '1234' it ends up as '3412' because the cursor re-positions to the start of the text while they are typing.

Comment: Once the user gets to typing the 3 the if statement will be hit in your setter. Try using LostFocus as the attribute's value instead of PropertyChanged.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean. I have tried throwing the NotifyPropertyChange during the lostFocus event, but that prevents the user from changing the value at all.

Comment: I edited the answer with updated UpdateSourceTrigger value. Once the value 1234 is typed into the field and field loses focus, then the setter will be called.

Comment: Lost focus isn't a valid option in Silverlight. Thanks anyways, I did manage to get it working. It behaves differently when published than it does when running in debug.